# Assigning multiples variables at once in matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Given `MatX`, `MatY` and `MatZ`, I have the following assignments:

```
x = np.dot([s**3, s**2, s, 1], np.dot(
    transpose(self.B), np.dot(
    np.transpose(self.MatX, np.dot(
    self.MatX, np.dot(
    self.B, np.transpose([t**3, t**2, t, 1])))))))

y = np.dot([s**3, s**2, s, 1], np.dot(
    transpose(self.B), np.dot(
    np.transpose(self.MatY, np.dot(
    self.MatY, np.dot(
    self.B, np.transpose([t**3, t**2, t, 1])))))))

z = np.dot([s**3, s**2, s, 1], np.dot(
    transpose(self.B), np.dot(
    np.transpose(self.MatZ, np.dot(
    self.MatZ, np.dot(
    self.B, np.transpose([t**3, t**2, t, 1])))))))
```

This is very redundant since I am only changing `Mat?` in each case. Is there a way to assign `[x,y,z]` directly with some sort of shortcut to avoid copy and pasting the code each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a function:

```
def foo(Mat, B):
    result = np.dot([s**3, s**2, s, 1], np.dot(B.T, np.dot(np.transpose(Mat, np.dot(Mat, np.dot(B, np.transpose([t**3, t**2, t, 1])))))))
    return result

x = foo(self.MatX, self.B)
y = ....
z = ....
```

Other variables, `s` and `t` could be passed as arguments or taken from the environment.